# Export Functionality not working in .Net4.0 based windows application

Tags: .net, windows

I have developed a windows application (.NET4.0 framework and C#) which has an export functionality wherein data is exported and written in local hard drive in .doc format
The application works fine in windows xp but on vista and windows 7 export functionality doesn't work if installation is done by a non admin user . The export function is unable to write on the harddrive.
Am i missing something in creating the setup? How to have the application with enhanced level of user writes

I am using US2010 for development

Thanks
Prashant

Comment: What errors/exceptions are thrown?

Comment: hi, with our business software we have the same problem. we resolve this with a nasty trick, we install the software not under "Programs" but in a own directory.

Answer (score 0):

If ClickOnce is an option for you then you may find looking into that to be a solution, each install has it's data folder for easy and secure data reading/writing.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx) details accessing local and remote data from your application.